# Find Server name on postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku-postgres

I have made a PostgreSQL database, and I am trying to connect a python script to it. I need to enter the server name to the script. I have the database name, but I don't know what the server name is. Where do I find that? If it helps I am working through Heroku Postgres.

Comment: Heroku's dashboard doesn't give you the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

The [official article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python) in the DevCenter states:

> To use PostgreSQL as your database in Python applications you will need to use the psycopg2 [...] to connect to DATABASE_URL in your code.

So I guess there is no server name needed with that package.

Comment: The URL will contain the server name.